# Auto turn off switch during power outage

Tags: switches, surge-protection, home-automation

In my area power outages are a daily routine. And power surges, which occur when the electricity comes back, makes it even worse. To avoid damage of the electronic devices we try to unplug them quickly. However, if we are out of the house, this is not possible.

So, I was thinking of some sort of "automatic switch" which disconnects the device from its power source by opening the circuit when there is a power outage, and which requires human action to turn back ON again.

Is there any simple switch or device that can do this task?

Comment: Most manual 'contactors' (industrial switches) have this 'zero volt drop-out' facility, mainly to stop machine tools suddenly restarting themselves when power is restored after an unexpected power cut. You wouldn't need one per device, you can get ones big enough to use one per circuit, or one per house. Supply your lighting and refrigeration directly, and everything else through the contactor.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried to search online for the 'zero volt drop-out' device but I can't find anything. Can you please mention an example of a commercial product that I can get online?

Comment: Yes, I couldn't either until I got creative in my search terms. Try [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Release-Button-Woodshop-Metalwork-Machines/dp/B0768VW6N9). It seems that NVR, 'no volt release', is the term to search for, 'NVR switch' throws up lots of good examples

Comment: @Neil_UK Thank you so much. This is exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMyh08.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You could also use a 12Vdc relay powered by small 12Vdc on the power strip to drive coil. But then you need a 12V bat to Reset

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler arrangement is this: -

[image]

But the pushbutton does need to be rated for full load current.